# Default Web Directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have setup a site in IIS and then within the site, application, as follows:

Sites
--> Site
------> Application

When I publish the application from Visual Studio 2013, all works well when I browse to server:port/Application.

However, when I get the app to point to a specific page, it goes to

```
server:port/Application/SpecificPage
```

not

```
server:port/SpecificPage
```

There is obviously a setting in Visual Studio or IIS, but I can't find it.

Any pointers would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: This is because you've deployed your app into `/Application`. Why not deploy to the root of the site?

Comment: I thought the point was that each site could have multiple apps and the IIS structure supported this.  Only by using the Default Site would you get away from that.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple apps in the same site, but there is also only one root application (obviously). So, is there already an app residing in the root of your site?

Comment: Would be happy to take this to a chat room and do this in real time.

Comment: How would we proceed?